# Typescript react-select Custom Input Component InputProps type is incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I cannot type the `inputProps` of React-Select's Input Component. I checked the `Input.d.ts`, but it seems the InputProps interface is different from the other component such as ControlProps or OptionProps.

**How should I implement it so that I can access the current `input value` and `options` inside the CustomInput component?**

```
const CustomInput = (inputProps: any) => {
    ...
    return (
      <>
        <components.Input {...inputProps} />
        ...
      </>
    );
  };
```

```
<RcSelect
   components={{
     ...
     Input: CustomInput,
   }}
   ...
/>
```

*Using any works for my purpose, but I need to type it to eliminate lint warning.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change **inputProps** type from `any` to `InputProps` by importing type `InputProps`, and in order to get options and value you have to destruct your object `inputProps`.

CustomInput.ts

```
import Select, {InputProps,OptionType,OptionsType,} from 'react-select';

const CustomInput = (inputProps: InputProps) => {
  const getValue: () => OptionsType<OptionType> = inputProps.getValue;
  const options: OptionsType = inputProps.options;
        
  console.log('value', getValue()); // <==== value
  console.log(options); // <==== options
        
  return <input {...inputProps} />; //
};
```

You can check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-jtpxxf?file=index.tsx